# How to disable caps lock overlay for games?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, acer-travelmate

I know topics about video games are off topic for this site but I believe this question still fits because I am asking about other software/drivers that happen to interact with a game.

I have an Acer TravelMate 5744 Series laptop, when the caps lock button is pressed there is an overlay on the screen to indicate if caps lock has been turned on or off. This overlay seems to cause problems with the game Morrowind and severely limits my FPS until the game is restarted. The simple solution would be to disable this overlay but I cannot find a option to do so.

Comment: Uninstall the Acer software that handles this.

Comment: @Ramhound That would work but I do not know what software actually does the overlay (otherwise I could just probably kill the executable before running my game).

Comment: You will have to figure that out.  There can't be a large amount of software that Acer provides for your laptop.  You didn't provide specifics about an exact model version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question quite similar to yours was asked [HERE](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-32544_102-562221/turning-off-caps-lock-display/). He too had an Acer device. In the end, [DoctorPanacea](http://www.cnet.com/profile/DoctorPanacea/) came up with a working solution.

He stated that a program by the name of `HotkeyUtility.exe` was causing it, and suggested using the software [THIS](http://www.system-tray-cleaner.com/systray/programs.php?appid=6096B6517F36DE8223CF5E0749BE152D00099A20) site offers to remove it. If you don't feel comfortable installing this third party software, I reckon that you could also rename `C:\Program Files\Acer\Hotkey Utility\HotkeyUtility.exe` to `C:\Program Files\Acer\Hotkey Utility\HotkeyUtility.exe.old`. This should stop it from starting on startup, or being automatically started by other software on your computer (after a reboot of your computer).

If the problem persists, and Task Manager shows a task by the name of `BTTray.exe`, trying [THIS](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/caps-lock-notification-appears-on-the-screen-when/285a5edf-eb03-4e19-93c3-63e869486180) registry hack suggested on the Microsoft Community website might also work.

Comment: Well the item you linked to contained the answer but it was not the one mentioned by DoctorPanacea but rather the one marked as the solution (written by dardisco). The solution he listed was related to the program Launch Manager and not HotkeyUtility. He suggested deleting the image files that are displayed. Instead I have used task manager to kill the program "LManager.exe" found in the Program Files directory he mentions.

Comment: @Fr33dan Its good that you managed to solve the problem. Do my instructions work at all to disable the overlay? If not, is it okay if I replace my instructions with your ones that helped you solved the problem?

Comment: No they do not work at all. My computer does not even have the HotkeyUtility installed.